# Enviar correos desde Python

Tags: python, email, smtp

Estoy intentando enviar un correo en un script de Python, para automatizar alarmas. He conseguido enviarlo, pero el servidor rechaza el envío:

```
port = 465  # For SSL

context = ssl.create_default_context()

message = "message = 'Subject: {ALERTA - LOS DISPOSITIVOS NO TRANSMITEN}\n\n{LOS DISPOSITIVOS NO HAN TRANSMITIDO EN LOS ULTIMOS 30 MINUTOS}'.format(SUBJECT, TEXT)"
sender_email = "****"
receiver_email = "****"

smtp_server = "****"
password = "****"

with smtplib.SMTP_SSL(smtp_server, port, context=context) as server:
    server.login(sender_email, password)
    server.sendmail(sender_email, receiver_email, message)
```

Error del servidor de correo:

> MX: aspmx.l.google.com RESP: 5.7.1 [91.239.43.167 11] Our system has detected that this message is 5.7.1 not RFC 5322 compliant: 5.7.1 'From' header is missing. 5.7.1 To reduce the amount of spam sent to Gmail, this message has been 5.7.1 blocked. Please visit 5.7.1 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=RfcMessageNonCompliant 5.7.1 and review RFC 5322 specifications for more information. sg18si4811253ejc.10 - gsmtp

La verdad es que estoy algo perdido con el error.

Gracias de antemano!

Un saludo.

Comment: Te alega que el "From: pepita@midominio.com" está mal. Probablemente `sender_email` tenga un valor incorrecto, pero como lo has ocultado, imposible saber.

Comment: Básicamente está diciendo que tu mensaje es Spam y por eso ha sido bloqueado, el link que sale en el error te explica como solucionarlo.

Comment: Si usas tu cuenta de google, entonces el problema es que google rechaza tu correo por que puede ser sapm. Para solucionar esto existen las cunetas de aplicación que te brinda google

Comment: No, el problema es que el mensaje que se está creando no sigue el estándar. Y por ello google sospecha que pueda ser spam, pero en realidad eso del spam es aquí una _falsa pista_. El verdadero problema es el formato del mensaje

Comment: @abulafia bien visto!. Yo solo me fijé en el error >_<

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Está mal la forma en que creas el mensaje. Tal como lo tienes, el mensaje contiene una sentencia python, lo que no tiene mucho sentido:

```
message = "message = 'bla bla'.format(SUBJECT, TEXT)"
```

En realidad debería contener solo el 'bla bla' y no todo lo demás. Se ve que has intentado adaptar código de otro sitio sin entenderlo bien.

El mensaje ha de contener una serie de cabeceras (opcionales), después una línea en blanco, y finalmente el cuerpo del mensaje, terminado por una línea que contenga un solo punto.

Una forma sencilla de hacerlo es con las cadenas de "triple comilla" que pueden ocupar varias líneas

```py
message = '''
Subject: {ALERTA - LOS DISPOSITIVOS NO TRANSMITEN}

{LOS DISPOSITIVOS NO HAN TRANSMITIDO EN LOS ULTIMOS 30 MINUTOS}
.
'''
```

La cabecera "From" de la que se quejaba el error es en realidad opcional. Creo que el error se debía simplemente a que el contenido del mensaje no era válido y no a que faltase esa cabecera. En cualquier caso, si sigue dando el mismo problema, añade bajo la cabecera "Subject:" otra que diga "From:" y que repita el email del remitente (es el mismo que tuviste que pasar como parámetro a `server.send_mail()`, pero en el caso de esta función se utiliza para construir el *envelope* del mensaje, y no su contenido)

Comment: todo claro, muchas gracias @abulafia!